# Grouping customers during registration (in Magento)

Tags: php, magento, customization

I'm using **Magento CE** 1.6 eCommerce engine and I need to **assign a group** to my customers automatically during the registration process.

Logical process it's quite simple: *if the registration email address domain is listed as special add it to the `special` group, else do nothing*.
I need also to create and manage this special domains list.

For eg.: if `foo.com` is listed as special domain, the user `bar@foo.com` will be added to the `special` group.

Need some way to extend the controller?
Where to start to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use Magento Observers and look around the `customer_save` or `customer_save_before` event.